# How does the pnorm aspect of work with z scores & x-values?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

My professor assigned us some homework questions regarding normal distributions. We are using R studio to calculate our values instead of the z-tables.

One question asks about something about meteors where the mean (μ) = 4.35, standard deviation (σ) = 0.59 and we are looking for the probability of x>5.
**I already figured out the answer with 1-pnorm((5-4.35)/0.59) ~ 0.135.**

**However**, I am currently having some difficulty trying to understand what pnorm calculates.

Originally, I just assumed that z scores were the only arguments needed. So I proceeded to use pnorm(z-score) for most of the normal curvature problems. 
The help page for pnorm accessed through ?pnorm() indicates that the usage is:
*pnorm(q, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)*.

My professor also says that I am ignoring the mean and sd by just using pnorm(z-score). I feel like it is just easier to type in one value instead of the whole set of arguments. So I experimented and found that
**1-pnorm((5-4.35)/0.59) = 1-pnorm(5,4.35,0.59)**

So it looks like **pnorm(z-score) = pnorm (x,μ,σ)**.

> Is there a reason that using the z-score allows to skip the mean and
>   standard deviation in the pnorm function?

I have also noticed that trying to add μ,σ arguments with the z-score gives the wrong answer **(ex: pnorm(z-score,μ,σ).**

```
> 1-pnorm((5-4.35)/0.59)
[1] 0.1352972
> pnorm(5,4.35,0.59)
[1] 0.8647028
> 1-pnorm(5,4.35,0.59)
[1] 0.1352972
> 1-pnorm((5-4.35)/0.59,4.35,0.59)
[1] 1
```

Comment: What answer are you hoping to get from your final example? You're basically saying "on a normal distribution with mean 4.35 and standard deviation 0.59, how much probability is above x = 1.1?" Compare that to `curve(dnorm(x, mean = 4.35, sd = 0.59), from = 0, to = 10)`.

Comment: I was trying to understand why the pnorm() function accepted two different ways of values for the same answer. One way was by just putting in the z-score and working with that. The other way was inputting the x,μ, and σ. This issue is probably more theoretical than programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because a z-score is standard normally distributed, meaning it has `μ = 0` and `σ = 1`, which, as you found out, are the default parameters for `pnorm()`.

The z-score is just the transformation of any normally distributed value to a standard normally distributed one.

So when you output the probability of the z-score for `x = 5` you indeed get the same value than asking for the probability of `x > 5` in a  normal distribution with `μ = 4.35` and `σ = 0.59`.

But when you *add* `μ = 4.35` and `σ = 0.59` to your z-score inside `pnorm()` you get it all wrong, because you're looking for a standard normally distributed value in a different distribution.

`pnorm()` (to answer your first question) calculates the *cumulative density function*, which shows you `P(X < x)` (the probability that a random variable takes a value equal or less than `x`). That's why you do `1 - pnorm(..)` to find out P(X > x).